# STAT Relation on a related model's STAT relation, Yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii, relational-database

I am having a problem with STAT relation in Yii. I am not sure whether what I am looking for is possible with native Yii relations. I will try my best to describe my issue, Please ask for any specific details if something is not clear.

I have three table and hence three models

```
| tablea         |
| tableb         |
| tablec         |


mysql> select * from tablea;
+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
|  1 | Item 1 |
|  2 | Item 2 |
+----+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from tableb;
+----+------+----------+
| id | Aid  | name     |
+----+------+----------+
|  1 |    1 | B Item 1 |
|  2 |    2 | B Item 2 |
|  3 |    1 | B Item 3 |
+----+------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from tablec;
+----+------+----------+-------+
| id | Bid  | name     | value |
+----+------+----------+-------+
|  1 |    1 | C Item 1 |    10 |
|  2 |    2 | C Item 2 |    20 |
|  3 |    1 | C Item 3 |    15 |
|  4 |    2 | C Item 4 |     5 |
|  5 |    3 | C Item 5 |    12 |
+----+------+----------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The relation is like TableA HAS_MANY TableB and TableB HAS_MANY TableC.

I have a value field in TableC. I am able to get the STAT relation for the sum of value from TableB. What I want is the sum of all the TableC items from TableA. I need to used= them in the GridView with sorting capability.

Any Idea on how to implement this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try joining the third table onto the relation in your `TableA` model like so:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        ...
        'TableCCount' => array(self::STAT, 'TableB', 'Aid', 'join'=>'INNER JOIN `tablec` `tc` ON `tc`.`Bid` = `t`.`id`'),
        ...
    );
}
```

Not tested, so might need a little editing.

Comment: Thanks, this is working. But this is not fully using relations, we are using table name in join. Is this is the native Yii way to achieve this? I am wondering why we can't use 'through' in STAT relation.